# Blank page received - hosting Node + Express + Angular app on iis using iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I am trying to host express nodejs app with having angular as front end on IIS 8.5 using iisnode.

I followed exactly all the steps mentioned in iisnode wiki page. I am receiving blank page every time I hit any page through url.

My express server.js file is in server folder and angular file is in public/app folder named app.js

I am using express routing and on angular front I am using ui routing. My web.config is as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="sendToNode">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server/server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\node\node.exe"/>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please try to change `<match url="/*" />` to `<match url=".*" />`?

Comment: Yeah tried that, it is redirecting to server.js which in turn tries to run application on given port and fails with error like EACCESS port already in use as the application was already running. I think I might be wrong in configuring url rewrite. What should be the url attribute value in rules?